# List not re-loading from firestore in base view on dismiss of .sheet in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I have another question.

I have a demo app where I add a ToDo in a Firestore database. From the base View I open a .sheet with a TextEditor where I enter data and save it into Firestore database. But on dismiss the List of ToDos in the base View is gone and is not refreshed until I go to another tab in the app and return back.

I have a ViewModel where I use a Firebase snapshot listener.

Code of the base View:

import Firebase
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseStorage

```
struct HomeMenuView: View {
    @ObservedObject var toDosViewModel = ToDosViewModel()
    @Binding var showAddToDoView: Bool
    @State private var showModifyToDoView = false
    @State private var note = ""
    @State private var selectedToDoId = ""
    
    func removeRow(at offset:IndexSet) {
        for index in offset {
            toDosViewModel.deleteNote(noteToDelete: toDosViewModel.todos[index].id!)
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            VStack (alignment: .center){
                List() {
                    ForEach(toDosViewModel.todos) { todo in
                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                            Text(todo.notes)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.tabBarColor)
                                .lineLimit(2)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    showAddToDoView = true
                                    selectedToDoId = todo.id!
                                    note = todo.notes
                                }
                        }
                        .listRowSeparatorTint(Color.tabBarColor)
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: removeRow)
                }
                .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                .onAppear() {
                    toDosViewModel.subscribe()
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showAddToDoView) {
            VStack() {
                HStack () {
                    Button("Save") {
                        guard !note.isEmpty else
                        { showAddToDoView = false; return }
                        toDosViewModel.addNote(notes: note)
                        note = ""
                        showAddToDoView = false
                    }
                    .offset(x: 20)
                    Spacer()
                    Button("Back") {
                        note = ""
                        showAddToDoView = false
                    }
                    .offset(x: -20)
                }
                .frame(height: 50, alignment: .center)
                TextEditor(
                    text: $note
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import UIKit

class ToDosViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var todos = [ToDo]()
    @Published var errorMessage: String?
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?
    
    func subscribe() {
        if listenerRegistration == nil {
            listenerRegistration = db.collection("todos")
                .order(by: "timestamp", descending: true)
                .addSnapshotListener { [weak self] (querySnapshot, error) in
                    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                        print("No documents")
                        return
                    }
                    
                    self?.todos = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
                        let result = Result { try queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: ToDo.self) }
                        
                        switch result {
                        case .success(let todo):
                            if let todo = todo {
                                self?.errorMessage = nil
                                return todo
                            }
                            else {
                                self?.errorMessage = "Document doesn't exist."
                                return nil
                            }
                        case .failure(let error):
                            switch error {
                            case DecodingError.typeMismatch(_, let context):
                                self?.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
                            case DecodingError.valueNotFound(_, let context):
                                self?.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
                            case DecodingError.keyNotFound(_, let context):
                                self?.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(context.debugDescription)"
                            case DecodingError.dataCorrupted(let key):
                                self?.errorMessage = "\(error.localizedDescription): \(key)"
                            default:
                                self?.errorMessage = "Error decoding document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
                            }
                            return nil
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    
    func addNote(notes: String) {
        db.collection("todos").document().setData(["notes" : notes, "timestamp" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()])
    }
    
    func modifyNote(noteToModify: String, notes: String) {
        db.collection("todos").document(noteToModify).setData(["notes" : notes, "timestamp" : FieldValue.serverTimestamp()])
    }
    
    func deleteNote(noteToDelete: String) {
        db.collection("todos").document(noteToDelete).delete()
    }
}
```

Any idea what the issue could be?

Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems you just want to handle changes between snapshots, right? So something is added it can be added to your dataSource, or if something is modified it can be modified? As is, it looks like every time there's any kind of change you're reloading everything. Perhaps taking a look at [View Changes Between Snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots) would help.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@ObservedObject var toDosViewModel = ToDosViewModel()
```

To

```
@StateObject var toDosViewModel = ToDosViewModel()
```

Comment: Indeed this works, but in this case the data is owned by the view, but why is the view not reloading the data directly from the Firestore DB on dismiss of the .sheet? Is it really ment to be like that?